# No FileSystem for scheme "gs" in apache airflow

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

am trying to submit my scala Jar using `SparkSubmitOperator` in airflow, I have set configurations for gs, am not sure are they in right place, below is how my DAG looks like

```
SparkSubmitOperator(task_id='spark_task',
 application = 'gs://xxx/xxx/xxx.jar',
 conf = {"spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts":True, "spark.blacklist.enabled":False, "fs.gs.impl":True, "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem":False "fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl":False, "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS":True},
    conn_id='spark_local',
    java_class = 'com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    jars="gs://xxx/xxx/*",
    application_args=["xxx" "xxx" "xxx", "xxx"])
```

**am getting this exception** [image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with spark but if you check [SparkSubmitOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.html#SparkSubmitOperator) is inspected, it uses [SparkHook.submit](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_modules/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_submit_hook.html#SparkSubmitHook.submit). Upon checking `SparkHook.submit`, forms a `spark-submit` command. Based from this [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) support file systems are `hdfs://` path or a `file:// path`.

Comment: Instead of directly referencing a GCS path, can you try hosting the file on your cluster and use the local file system?

Comment: No @RiccoD i have to place my  Jar at  cloud storage  location only

Comment: I see. You might need to install the [Cloud Storage connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage) on your cluster so you can access the files directly.

Comment: am using airflow  from google cloud composer should I install this cloud storage connector as a package ?

Comment: I could able to download the cloud storage connector  Jar, which I placed inside the plugin folder and restarted the airflow  tried running my DAG again I still see this exception

Comment: Based from the document, it should be installed on your Spark/Hadoop cluster.